# What is my nextElementSibling in my situation?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, styles, addeventlistener, siblings

I don't understand in this code, what is nextElementSibling and where do you take it from? Can anyone explain me? Thank you so much! Btw, my codes is not working and the console announces the mistake as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at HTMLButtonElement." Anybody knows what is wrong?
I will leave my codes in the comment section because of some reasons i can't leave it here. Sorry so much for this inconvinience!

Answer (score 0):

This is my codes. Sorry so much cause i can't attatch it in my question so i will leave it here. Thank you so much for helping me!

This is my JS:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible")

for (let i=0; i<coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active")

        var content = this.nextElementSibling

        if(content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null
        }else{
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px"
        }
    } )
}
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="mes.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="chat.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48a972c999.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--CHAT BAR BLOCK-->
    <div class="chat-bar-collapsible">
        <button id="chat-button" type="button" class="collapsible">Chat With Us! 
        <i id="chat-icon" style="color:#fff" class="fa fa-fw fa-comments-o"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="full-chat-block">
            <!--Mesage Container-->
            <div class="outer-container">
                <div class="chat-container">
                    <!--Message-->
                    <div id="chatbox">
                        <h5 id="chat-timestamp"></h5>
                        <p id="botStarterMessage" class="botText"><span>Loading...</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <!--User Input Box-->
                    <div class="chat-bar-input-block">
                        <div id="userInput">
                            <input type="text" id="textInput" class="input-box" name="msg" placeholder="Tap 'enter' to send a message">
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-bar-icon">
                            <i id="chat-icon" style="color:crimson" class="fa fa-fw fa-heart" onClick="heartButton()"></i>
                            <i id="chat-icon" style="color:#333" class="fa fa-fw fa-send" onClick="sendButton()"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div id="chat-bar-bottom">
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="mes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read these articles this will help you a lot. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! but my codes also do not work! i edited my question so that you can see! it'd be kind of you if you could help!